# why do virtual machine check the field type?

Tags: java

As an example, take a *getstatic* bytecode opcode.
JVM perfoms a check whether the reference field is static(or may be instance?)
Isn't it redundant step? Because, compiler ensures the field is static.
PS perhaps, the point is bytecode could be altered during the run time.

Comment: Who says I used a compiler to create my bytecode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't it redundant step? Because, compiler ensures the field is static.

If someone creates the bytecodes by hand (or using a bytecode modification library), then those compiler checks don't happen.  That's why we need to verify the bytecodes ... at load time.

Comment: The verification can also be skipped using the VM flag `-Xverify:none`. This is especially useful for programs like Eclipse, which has long loading times because of it

Comment: Do you have any objective evidence for that?  Like >>how much<< it speeds up Eclipse startup?

Comment: Not really, but considering the shear amount of classes I think it's not negotiable.

Comment: Well, I also don't have evidence, but I'd be very surprised if verification contributed more than 10% to the startup time.  Which makes this a dubious "optimization" ... IMO.

Comment: If it takes 30 seconds to load, that's still 3 seconds every day, which obviously adds up. But anyway, the option is there if you need it, and I doubt a 'pure' Eclipse installation contains malicious bytecode.